# Show that $\mathbb R$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $\mathbb R$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ \{1}. An idea was to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, but I cannot seem to apply it.I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Do you remember what the topological definition of a "connected space" is? Is $\mathbb{R}$ connected? Is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ connected? Can a connected space be homeomorphic to a non-connected one?

Comment: Can it be shown without using the notion of connectedness? @MikeHaskel

Comment: @user123 You have the Intermediate Value Theorem; this is basically a statement about the connectedness of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and the fact that the image of connected set is connected.  So if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ is a homeomorphism, then there are $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) < 1< f(y)$. But then IVT implies there is $z$ between $x$ and $y$ so that $f(z)=1$.

Comment: @Hayden Then how can you show the contradiction. That there does not exist $f(z)=1$. Or it can be deduced directly since 1 is not part of the image.

Comment: The image is contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$, so can there be such a $z$?